# how to set a color based on base color value and alpha value in xml?

Tags: android, layout, colors, styles, themes

I want to set a custom color.

In the spec I was given this color definition:

```
#5F6368(google_grey700) and 10% opacity
```

How can I define my color using this base resource + alpha value?

Possible via xml? or has to be grammatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="ripple_theme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/green</item>
  </style>    
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your color as #1A5F6368 in your colors xml as 1A at start of color specify 10% opacity. color defination in hexadecimal is #AARRGGBB

Explanation

```
# AA(Alpha) RR(Red) GG(Green) BB(Blue)
```

Comment: Thanks! so it is #105F6368 and not #1A5F6368 right?

Comment: Its is #1A5F6368

Comment: can you please explain why 1A is valued 10 ?